# Reload php on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos

I have a webserver running with nginx on a CentOS.
I altered my php.ini file to increrase some limits, but when I try to restart php, I get error messages :

```
[root@server ~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 23 2014 15:09:34)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.

[root@server ~]# systemctl restart php-fpm56.service‏
Failed to issue method call: Unit php-fpm56.service\xe2\x80\x8f.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

[root@server ~]# systemctl restart php56.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit php56.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

[root@server ~]# service nginx reload
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl reload  nginx.service

[root@server ~]# service nginx restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  nginx.service

[root@server ~]# systemctl restart php-fpm.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit php-fpm.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

[root@server ~]# systemctl restart php.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit php.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

[root@server ~]# systemctl restart php56.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit php56.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Any idea how to restart PHP please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should restart Apache, not trying to restart PHP.

Comment: I don't run Apache, I run Nginx, and as you can see in my post, I already tried to restart http server : service nginx restart but has no effect

Comment: So, you can try to restart Nginx. There is no PHP service running in servers

Comment: How about `service php5-fpm restart`?

Comment: What did you change in the ini?

Comment: `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol, ok, you gave me a lead to find out the solution !
I tried the old fashion way : service php-fpm56 restart and it worked. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I though the old fashion way was the solution : **`service php-fpm56 restart`** (actually it worked because I typed it in the SSH terminal)

I was wondering what were the \xe2\x80\x8f. It appears to be some extra caracters added when I copy / pasted from skype to ssh terminal.

So **`systemctl restart php-fpm56.service‏`** would have work if I typed it instead of copy/paste it from skype...

Thanks to everyone